# Stone-Geary preferences and competitive equilibrium

Tags: reference-request, preferences, general-equilibrium, nash-equilibrium, competitive-equilibrium

Does anybody know if a competitive equilibrium obtains under Stone-Geary preferences; are there multiple equilibria problems; do such preferences admit an analysis with *more* than one type of representative agents; any *good+relevant* resources on the subject?

Comment: When you ask if there is a competitive equilibrium, what is the specification for the firm's side? Are you asking just for papers that use Stone-Geary in a competitive model? I don't think the question as it stands is clear, and this post contains multiple questions, which we usually ask to be separated.

Comment: I am not sure if this fits the bill, but just in case http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2937865.pdf?refreqid=excelsior%3A3adaa806a3a46fc10d857d7d1856be53

Comment: Don't forget to assign the bounty! :)

Comment: next to the answer, below the tick, there should be a button in light blue. You need to press it.

Comment: My bad. The bounty was not created by you! Sorry. Its the user "Farewell Stack Exchange" who has to assign the bounty.

Comment: No, check the text in the bounty. In any case, the bounty will not be asigned because the user was suspended :( See [here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/14433/farewell-stack-exchange). @Fato

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This is a paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2937865.pdf?refreqid=excelsior:3adaa806a3a46fc10d857d7d1856be53) using a competitive monopolistic framework (in GE). It is an old paper by Stratz (1989). Recent work with Stone-Geary preferences relates to the issue of structural transformation following the work of Herrendorf, Rogerson and Valentinyi (2013), although there is considerable debate on whether these preferences appropriately capture the data. All these papers have a representative consumer, with expenditure shares changing over time due to growth.